# Insertar usuario Logueado

Tags: php, html, mysql

perdon la molestia.
Tengo el siguiente codigo, donde se logra exitosamente el login, pero no me inserta el usuario (que en este caso es el DNI) en el header cuando logra acceder al dashboard.
Lo demas funciona bien, tanto el login como el logout, la conexion con la base de datos.
Este es el index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Acceso a Clientes</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<form action="validar.php" method="post">

<h1>SISTEMA LOGIN</h1>
<p>Usuario <input type="text"placeholder="Ingrese su DNI" name="usuario" require> </p>
<p>Contraseña<input type="password"placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" name="password" require > </p>

<input type="submit" value="ingresar">


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Este es el validar.php

```html
<?php

include('db.php');

$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


$sql= "SELECT*FROM personal WHERE usuario='$usuario' and password='$password'";
$resultado= mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas){
    header("location:mostrar_contenido.php");

}else{
    include("index.php");
    ?>
    <h1>ERROR DE AUTENTICACION</h1>
    <?php
    
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Este seria el mostrar_contenido.php:

```html
<?php
  require 'db.php';
  session_start();



  ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bienvenido!</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php require 'partials/header.php' ?>

      <br><center>Se ha ingresado con exito!</center>


      <img src="acceso_cliente.png">
      <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y por ultimo, el header.php donde debe mostrar el dni del usuario luego del bienvenido, y el exit que apunta al logout para luego redirigir al index.php.

```html
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true)
?>
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  Bienvenido! <?echo $_SESSION['usuario'];?>   <a href="logout.php">Exit</a>
</header>
```

MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS A TODOS POR LA AYUDA DE SIEMPRE!

Comment: En el código de tu pregunta no veo que definas lo que es $_SESSION['usuario'] en ninguna parte (ni el loggedin)... pon eso para que veamos como lo haces.

Answer (score 1):

Falta definir la sesión del usuario y el session_start() también

```
session_start();
include('db.php');

$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


$sql= "SELECT*FROM personal WHERE usuario='$usuario' and password='$password'";
$resultado= mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas){
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header("location:mostrar_contenido.php");

}else{
    include("index.php");
    ?>
    <h1>ERROR DE AUTENTICACION</h1>
    <?php
    
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ante todo. De todas maneras sigue sin mostrarme el nombre del usuario al loguearse.

Comment: @DiegoRanieri: Quizas cambiar `if($filas){` por `if($filas>0){`